# Why do many XML Serialization examples strip specific characters?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, xml-serialization

Many of the C# XML serialization examples here include code like

```
xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(60)));
xml = xml.Substring(0, (xml.LastIndexOf(Convert.ToChar(62)) + 1));
```

I understand this is discarding any (nonprintable/invalid) characters around < and >, but why do these characters exist in the first place?

Assume UTF16 using Encoding.Unicode with an XmlTextWriter.

Comment: This actually discard all characters (not just "unprintable/invalid" ones) before the first '<' and after the last '>'. Where have you seen an example that does that?

Comment: I'm not sure where the original coder found it, but plenty of examples by searching for [xmlserializer convert.tochar(62)](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=xmlserializer+convert.tochar\(62\))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assume UTF16 using Encoding.Unicode with an XmlTextWriter.

The UTF format is not really a player in this as much as the construction of the XmlTextWriter.  If the XmlTextWriter is handed a StringReader containing your xml variable, then the problem would potentially exist in how the xml was originally read from disk.

Text files often include an encoding preamble called a BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).  When read incorrectly, several 'weird' characters will appear before the content of the file.

I expect the code you have was a poor man's attempt at removing the BOM from an incorrectly read text file.

Comment: Plausible, but why discard all data after the last '>'?

Comment: This is just an object passed to XmlSerializer - it didn't hit the disk at any time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660440/c-xml-serialization-leading-question-marks seems to back up your answer. I'm sending XML to SQL Server so I'll check our encoding there.

Answer (score 1):

It is, so far as I know, just an example of Postel's Law, otherwise known as the Robustness Principle.  There shouldn't be anything there, but we might as well strip it away just in case.

> Be conservative in what you send; be liberal in what you accept

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_Principle

You may also want to check the XML specification since ignoring that extraneous text may actually be required and  not just a polite convenience